# How to reduce if-condition looping - Swift

Tags: swift, performance, loops, if-statement, reduce

I know it sounds crazy, but just curious how I can reduce the if loop iteration for following? I have tried using `guard let` but stucked at some place.

```
{
        if arenaEventItems == nil || arenaEventItems.count <= 0 {
            return
        }
        if (arenaEventItems.count > 0 && (self.arenaEvents?.monthsDictObjList.count)! > 0){
            if (self.tableView != nil){
            if let arrVisibleRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows as? [IndexPath]{
                if (self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!.count > 0){
                    let indexPath : IndexPath =   self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!.first!
                    if let dict  = self.arenaEvents?.monthsDictObjList[indexPath.row] {
                        if(self.arenaHeaderView != nil) && (dict.count) > 0 {
                            self.arenaHeaderView?.setMonthTitle(string: (dict.keys.first!))
                            let selectedMonthTitle = (dict.keys.first!)

                            for month in  (self.arenaEvents?.uniqueMonthOnlyList)! {
                                if (selectedMonthTitle.contains(month)){
                                    selectedMonthIndex = (self.arenaEvents?.uniqueMonthOnlyList.index(of: month)!)!
                                    break
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: You are not following **Swift** language guidelines. Mixing `nil` checking with `optional-binding` many times. Unnecessary annotating type `IndexPath`. Nested `if` conditions might be used as combined. Lots more...

Comment: @PriyankaMistry Don't forget to upvote helpful answers and accept the most helpful one with the green checkmark. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce it like that, without any forced unwrapping or nesting:

```
guard let arenaEventItems = arenaEventItems,
    !arenaEventItems.isEmpty,
    let arenaEvents = self.arenaEvents,
    !arenaEvents.monthsDictObjList.isEmpty,
    let arenaHeaderView = self.arenaHeaderView,
    let indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first,
    let selectedMonthTitle = arenaEvents.monthsDictObjList[indexPath.row].keys.first
    else {
        return
}
arenaHeaderView.setMonthTitle(string: selectedMonthTitle)
if let monthIndex = arenaEvents.uniqueMonthOnlyList.index(where: { selectedMonthTitle.contains($0) }) {
    selectedMonthIndex = monthIndex
}
```

- you replace `if ... return` with `guard !... else return` to avoid nesting
- you replace `.count > 0` with `!...isEmpty` as best practice
- you replace multiple access to `self.something?` with `if let something = self.something` to avoid threading issues
- you unloop `for ... in ... { if (...) { ... } }` to `.index(where: ...)`

Comment: Thanks for suggesting best practice. Will try this code as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all the conditions in "if" and get something like this:

```
if let eventItems = arenaEventItems,
   eventItems.count > 0,
   let events = self.arenaEvents,
   !events.monthsDictObjList.isEmpty,
   let tableView = self.tableView,
   let arrVisibleRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows as? [IndexPath],
   !arrVisibleRows.isEmpty,
   let indexPath : IndexPath = arrVisibleRows.first,
   let dict = events.monthsDictObjList[indexPath.row],
   let headerView = self.arenaHeaderView,
   !dict.isEmpty {
        headerView.setMonthTitle(string: (dict.keys.first!))
        let selectedMonthTitle = (dict.keys.first!)

        for month in events.uniqueMonthOnlyList! {
            if (selectedMonthTitle.contains(month)){
                selectedMonthIndex = (events.uniqueMonthOnlyList.index(of: month)!)!
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `for ... in ... { if (...) { ... } }` construction can be reduced to `for ... in ... where ... { ... }`, as in `for month in events.uniqueMonthOnlyList! where selectedMonthTitle.contains(month) { selectedMonthIndex = ... } `. And the immediate `break` can be further simplified with `events.uniqueMonthOnlyList!.first(where: { ... })?...`

Comment: This is exactly the case when you should use `guard let`. A long `if` is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider restructuring your code, your code is not readable and incomprehensible for anyone who look at it. Since, you are using Swift, it is really easy to write such code with **guard ... else**, **if ... let** 
 pattern.

Some improvements that you can do on class is have your view non nil ie make them implicitly unwrapped optional, since you will always be connecting them to storyboard.

```
 @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
 @IBOutlet var arenaHeaderView: ArenaHeaderView!
```

Also, you have arrays which can go to nil, why do you want it to be nil. You could simply initialize an empty array and dictionaries. That way you can reduce some more comparison code like so,

```
arenaEventItems: [String: String] = [:]
```

With that changes and a bit of refactoring, you could possibly rewrite your code to something like this,

```
guard !arenaEventItems.isEmpty,
    let arenaEvents = arenaEvents,
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first,
    let dict = arenaEvents.monthsDictObjList[indexPath.row],
    let selectedMonthTitle = dict.keys.first

    else {
        return
}

arenaHeaderView.setMonthTitle(string: selectedMonthTitle)

for month in arenaEvents.uniqueMonthOnlyList where selectedMonthTitle.contains(month) {
    if let selectedIndex = arenaEvents.uniqueMonthOnlyList.index(of: month) {
        selectedMonthIndex = selectedIndex
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for brief detail. Will try to implement and update here.